# undefined variable that equals to a node module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I try to transpire my file using browserify or webpack.

This is my code:

```js
let rangy = require('rangy')
rangy.init()
const rang = () => rangy
```

After transpire my code and add in a html page, I try to get rangy in console, but when i type `rangy` and press enter button, js says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: rangy is not defined

When i type `rang()` and press enter, js says:

```
undefined
```

But line 2  runs correctly.

I need to use `rangy` in script tag of my `index.html`.

How can I do this?

This is my transpired file:

```js
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){


let rangy = require('rangy')
rangy.init()
const rang = () => rangy

},{"rangy":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){............
```

Comment: thanks @CertainPerformance. but this is a typing mistake in this question only. I modified question.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question if you are using webpack or not, but if you are then the problem you are having is that webpack wraps everything in a function so that all the webpack stuff doesn't interfere with other, external javascript libraries. Could you provide more details on your webpack configuration and which version of webpack you are using?

Comment: I use the lastest version of webpack. But result in browserfy and webpack are same.

Comment: Could you share the transpiled code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use webpack, and you are ok with `randy` leaking into the global scope, then just remove `let`:

```
rangy = require('rangy');
rangy.init();
```

`randy` variable will become available in the console.